# How to create and use android libraries jar?

Tags: java, android, jar

i have created simple android libraries project..

I choose New Android Application Project >> check "mark this project as library" and uncheck "create custom launcher icon" and uncheck "create activity"..

After that, i create simple class called MyClass.java and here's my code:

```
package android.external.jar;

public class MyClass {
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And then, i choose export >> Java >> Jar File >> uncheck all except src folder (it is included with AndroidManifest.xml) >> and build that JAR file..

I have another Android Application project for using that JAR File..

i have add external JAR to this project by doing right click on my project >> properties >> java build path >> libraries >> add external jar..

and it go like this :

[image: My Project Structure with external JAR files]

I've tried use that library to my application like this :

```
import android.external.jar.*;
...
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                    try {   
                        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), myClass.helloWorld(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
...
```

But it not works.. :(

and i got error like this:

[image: Error]

Does anyone know how to fix my problem?? Really need your suggestion..

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is you have to place your library in `libs` folder and then

You have to include your library and check your jar file in `properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`

Once clean the project and check once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I got this new error `TestingExternalLibs] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml' Should i delete AndroidManifest.xml on the jar files?

Comment: Ram kiran How if i need special permision like <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> in my library project?